# How can you make a path from a server?

Tags: c#

I made an application which generates some Excel documents, at this moment I will save it on my computer, what I want is to save it in a folder that I have in a network server as it would be the path.

Some example.

So I do it now

```
string path= @"";
string name= "Reporte_.xlsx";

while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, name)))
{                   
    name= string.Format("Report_{0}.xlsx", j);
    j++;
}

string fullpath = Path.Combine(path, name);
book.SaveAs(fullpath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
    false, false, 
    Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, 
    true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Comment: Change your `path` to the overall location you want- `string path = @"H:\my\path\to\location\ ` OR `string path = @"\\serverName\my\path\to\location\ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for UNC (Universal Naming Convention) syntax.

To form a UNC path, you need \server\share\folder\file.ext

```
const string mypath = @"\\serverName\shareName\test.txt";
System.IO.File.Create(mypath);
```